# copy TextField into variable that be used in another viewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

What I'm trying to do is that I created TextField in MainViewController where the user enter his/her id, so I code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var IdNum: UITextField!
```

and

```
var Id = self.IdNum.text
```

in viewDidLoad.

Now I want to take that value and use it in a button which belong to another `ViewController (FirstViewController)`

```
@IBAction func Messages(_ sender: UIButton) {                 

    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() == true {
        let recipients:[String] = ["1500"]
        let messageController = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageController.messageComposeDelegate  = self // implement delegate if you want
        messageController.recipients = recipients
        messageController.body = "*155*"+"Id"+"#"
        self.present(messageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Where the Id in `messageController.body = "*155*"+"Id"+"#"` is the TextFiled content, any help would be useful.

Comment: first thing first, if you do `var Id = self.IdNum.text in viewDidLoad` as soon as you will get out of viewDidLoad `Id` would be discarded, second strings are copied by value, so if you do that in did load, this will not be used in the future

Comment: @sken3r.MI  so where should I do it?

Comment: by another viewController you mean `MFMessageComposeViewController ` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send values to next screen as following:

```
let VCObejct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as? NextViewController
        VCObejct?.objToSend = obj//value to send
        navigationController?.pushViewController(VCObejct!, animated: true)
```

or

```
self.present(VCObejct, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You need to define objToSend in NextViewController as following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var vwPost: UIView?
```

You can also do it from storyboard by setting it up in Segue and using it the way Mar-k explained.